# How to capture DivisionUndefined error in decimal

Tags: python, exception, decimal

I'm trying to capture the DivisionUndefined error. However I can only capture the parent error InvalidOperation.

```
from decimal import Decimal, DivisionUndefined

try:
    Decimal('0')/Decimal('0')
except DivisionUndefined:
    print('spam')
```

Expected output:

```
spam
```

Actual output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test.py", line 4, in <module>
    Decimal('0')/Decimal('0')
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.DivisionUndefined'>]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the stack trace, the exception raised is not `DivisionUndefined` but `InvalidOperation`. So, in order to suppress the exception, you should catch `InvalidOperation`:

```py
from decimal import Decimal, InvalidOperation

try:
    Decimal('0')/Decimal('0')
except InvalidOperation:
    print('spam')
```

If you really want to handle only the `DivisionUndefined` case, I guess that you can do something like this:

```py
from decimal import Decimal, DivisionUndefined, InvalidOperation

try:
    Decimal('0')/Decimal('0')
except InvalidOperation as err:
    if err.args[0][0] is DivisionUndefined:
        print('spam')
    else:
        raise err
```

But I would not recommend that as neither the structure of the `err.args` nor the `DivisionUndefined` itself is documented.

And BTW, if you only want to supress the exception, you might want this:

```py
from decimal import Decimal, InvalidOperation, getcontext

c = getcontext()
c.traps[InvalidOperation] = False
Decimal('0')/Decimal('0')
```

Comment: I ended up doing something like this:

`except InvalidOperation as error:   if 'DivisionUndefined' in str(error):`

I'm not sure if this is better than your `if err.args[0][0] is DivisionUndefined` option, but thanks for the suggestion.